# How do we know that gravity emission is not time dilated like luminosity? $g'=γg$

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation

It seems like gravity emission would be expected to decrease with time dilation.  I've thought this from my first reading of Special and General Relativity, and I never heard a satisfying explanation why gravity emission is expected to remain constant.

Apparent time to an outside observer is dilated, $t'=γt$, where $γ$ is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor). This holds true for "everything else" (relativistic mass, relativistic momentum, length contraction), and especially the luminosity of a light bulb: $L'=γL$.  Why is it not reasonable to expect gravity emission to follow suit, $g'=γg$?  I would expect gravity emission to look identical to luminosity under time dilation.

It is said, "mass emits a constant amount of gravity in all frames of reference", but that seems to be the end of the explanation.  "It just is".

Dilating gravity emission would be the first step in any quantum theory of gravity.  It  implies that gravity is related to the number of "gravity particles" (ignoring their nature for now, but let's just say "gravitons"). Dilated luminosity relates to photons, dilated gravity emission relates to "gravitons".  The description doesn't need to be aware that it is related to particles, just as L'=γL isn't aware that light is comprised of photons.

It solves all sorts of problems, like the singularity problem of black holes.  With dilated gravity emission black hole singularities disappear from the math.  It does not disappear the event horizon, but it rather the event horizon becomes a relative, not absolute, limit.

Comment: Length, momentum, and luminosity/power don't transform that way. (For length the equation is $\ell'=\ell/γ$, not $\ell'=γ\ell$, if you consistent adopt the convention that the object is at rest in the unprimed frame.)

Comment: Yes you are correct about the Lorentz transformation for length contraction.  The question is using big "L" in reference to Luminosity, not length.  

To address what I think is a deeper concern, "everything else" including but not limited to relativistic mass, relativistic momentum, length contraction all undergo a Lorentz transformation, but yes, not necessarily the same one as time and luminosity, I'm assuming Luminosity undergoes the same as relativistic mass and time dilation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor#Occurrence